# Android & Java: Can't do any modifications with my App theme & App icon

Tags: java, android

as I'm very new to Android programming, this may be a simple question, but I was googling for an answer for hours now and all results did not work for me.

I'm using Android studio and I'd like to have an application Icon on the top left corner in my action bar.

I created a new project with a blank activity using Android V. 4.1 (API 16) as minSDK and API 21 as targetSDK.

When I compile & run the new project on my mobile device (Android V 4.3, Samsung G S3), I get the blank activity with an action bar that contains the activity title.

The tutorials on android's website always show an action bar that displays the app icon on the left side of the activity title, but it isn't displayed on my screen..

I googled for it and found solutions to "enable" the home icon in my MainActivity class (extends ActionBarActivity):

```
getActionBar().setIcon(R.id.launcher);
getActionBar().setLogo(R.id.launcher);
getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

Every of these three tries resulted in an error on my mobile device "application stopped"..

Then, I read that newer themes don't display the icon anymore. Is that correct?
Well, I don't know if it is correct, but I even can't change my theme.
Right now, by default, the app uses the `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`. My problem is, that I can't change it to some other theme like `Theme.Holo` or `Theme.Material`, I always get errors on my mobile device or Android Studio simply doesn't accept the theme.

Well, does anybody know what I'm doing wrong? I also tried to inherit my `MainActivity` from `Activity` instead of `ActionBarActivity`, but the result was always the same...

Answer (score 0):

Officially the support for showing App Icon or Logo in the `ActionBar` has been removed as per The **Material Design Guidelines**

You can't use Icon or any Logo especially if your using `AppCompat library`

Comment: Hi and thank's for your fast reply! So does that mean the Material theme is the newest and it is not recommended anymore to display app icons/logo in the action bar? If yes, then I don't see any good reason for that... If no, then can you tell me how I can use another theme, I'm not using the material theme, I'm using the AppCompat theme and I can't change it.. Android studio doesn't find a valid theme when I try to replace AppCompat with Holo or any else...

Comment: I guess you should not use Support Action Bar provided in AppCompat if you want a icon.
But more than it, I suggest making a Custom View for Action bar & then setting it will help you get : AppCompat + Logo

Comment: Hi Aky, when I only type `Theme.AppCompat`, does that automatically mean using the "Support Action Bar", or are there different kind of action bars in the category `Theme.AppCompat` (I don't mean the styles, I know there are Dark/Light versions)... I don't have a problem with using another theme, but I don't really know how to do it, because I can't use themes like `Theme.Holo` or `Theme.Material`, Android Studio marks them as undefined and won't let me compile it...

Comment: @Binary91
``Theme.AppCompat`` comes under AppCompat that means "Support Action Bar".

I have 2 solutions :
1. Use Custom Views & then set to action bar, I recommend this one & you can find nice articles to do this.
2. Switch back to default action bar instead of using Support Action Bar

Answer (score 0):

You should reference drawables in your application by `R.drawable`. `R.id` is normally used for the id of a View. Try to replace `setIcon(R.id.launcher)` with `setIcon(R.drawable.launcher)` .

Comment: Hi and thank you for the fast reply! Unfortunatelly, the app still crashes on my mobile device...